# Nonlinear 2D thermoconductivity equation(numerical solution)

Tags: nonlinear-equations, mathematica, differential-equations

I have to write a solver for 2D equation:
$$\partial_t u = u^2(\partial_x ^2 u + \partial_y ^2 u)$$
I try to use explicit method:
$$\partial_t u = \frac{u_{i,j}^{k+1} - u_{i,j}^k}{\tau}$$ and $$\partial_x ^2 u = \frac{u_{i-1,j}^k - 2u_{i,j}^k + u_{i+1,j}^k}{h^2}$$ and tha same for $\partial_y ^2 u$ with points $j-1, j, j+1$. Also I use: $$ u_{i,j}^k = \frac{u_{i+1,j}^k + u_{i,j}^k}{2}$$ for the coefficient before $\partial_x ^2$ and the same for $y$ with points $j+1, j$.
I wrote the following code in Mathematica:

```
nn = 6;
mm = 200;
h = 1./nn;
tau = 1./mm;
v0[x_, y_] := 1.;


Table[{x[i] = i*h, y[j] = j*h}, {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}];
Table[t[i] = i*t, {i, 0, mm}];
Table[u[i, j, 0] = v0[x[i], y[j]], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}];
Table[u[0, j, k] = 0, {j, 0, nn - 1}, {k, 0, mm}];
Table[u[nn, j, k] = 0, {j, 0, nn - 1}, {k, 0, mm}];
Table[u[i, 0, k] = 0, {i, 0, nn - 1}, {k, 0, mm}];
Table[u[i, nn, k] = 0, {i, 0, nn - 1}, {k, 0, mm}];

Do[ 
  u[i, j, k + 1] = 
   u[i, j, k] + 
    tau*(((u[i - 1, j, k] - 2*u[i, j, k] + u[i + 1, j, k])/
          h^2)*(( u[i, j, k] + u[i - 1, j, k])/
           2)^2 + ((u[i, j - 1, k] - 2*u[i, j, k] + u[i, j + 1, k])/
          h^2)*((u[i, j, k] + u[i, j - 1, k])/2)^2), {k, 0, mm}, {i, 
   1, nn - 1}, {j, 1, nn - 1}];



g[k_] := Table[u[i, j, k], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}];
p = Table[
  ListPlot3D[g[k], PlotRange -> {{0, nn}, {0, nn}, {0, 6}}], {k, 0, 
   mm, 20}]
```

I use the simpliest conditions:
$u(0,0,t) = u(10,10,t) = 0$ and $u(x,y,0) = 1$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why is u interpolated along x and y for the coefficient of the u diffusion? I assume "t" in the second equation is supposed to be delta t. Also, please format the code you've provided and specify what language is being used.

Comment: What are the initial/boundary conditions?

Comment: I see a u^h^2 term in the Mathematica code that is almost certainly a bug.

Comment: I've fixed the bug. Also I tried to use the coefficient as $u_{i,j,k}^2$ but it still doesn't work

Comment: You might clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: there are a lot of such problems as "Set::write: Tag InterpolatingFunction in <<1>> is Protected." and "General::stop: Further output of Set::write will be suppressed during this calculation."

Comment: You have several issues here: Your initial condition does not satisfy your boundary condition, your boundary condition is not even forced along the the edges of your domain (it is only enforced at two corners), I believe you conflate the spatial discretization $n$ for the temporal one $m$ several times and I don't see a time step for your Euler method.

Comment: I rewrote conditions in code And changed the initial conditions. I didn't clearly understand your comment about time step. Can you explain me this topic, please

Comment: I exchanged the "=" with "==" and solve the problem "Set::write: Tag InterpolatingFunction in <<1>> is Protected" this way. But know the Matematica does calculations but doesn't show me the result

Comment: I mistook the $\tau$ in your equations as something else, this was a mistake on my part. However, you still have more issues: You define `n` and `m` as floats when they need to be integers, for instance. I also don't run into the `Set:write` error that you seem to? You also cannot freely exchange `=` for `==`, they do very different things. I'm afraid this thread is going off the rails into the space of code debugging, which this site is not designed for. You might see Mathematica.SE for more help with the code, or simply spend some more time learning the syntax properly.

Comment: I have fixed all problems and now code's working:)